# Can Airport Time Capsule encrypted backups be hacked open from internet?

Tags: security, airport, time-capsule, encryption

Can Airport Time Capsule **encrypted** backups be hacked open from internet ?

How secure are the encrypted Airport Time Capsule backups exactly ? 
Any official docs anyone knows of ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Well first of all everything can be hacked. However you can make it as hard as possible. Use a strong password! Not abc123, password, your name, date of birth (easy to guess or find out on Facebook stuff) etc.

Time Machine uses the same encryption as FileVault 2, Kerberos, Keychain Services, Software Update Services etc. Encryption used is **XTS-AES-128 encryption with a 256-bit key.**

You can find more info on this page [Product security certifications, validations, and guidance for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201159)

Comment: Thanks man. I went over the doc that was very interesting but I didn't see any info about the TC or it's encrypted backups. Do you have a page number if I missed it please?